# Showing each quiz inquiry separately

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to make a quiz using PHP and Mysql. I have create my database and filled it. The database is construct as follows:  question_id(P.K),question, right answer, annswer1,answer2, answer3,level and test_id(F.K).

I have created a query that "draws" questions in a random order and I have shuffled the answers. The PHP script for showing the Qs and As to the user is the following:

```
while ($index <= (count($test)-1)){
 echo $test[$index]['question']. "<br/>";
 $question_id=$test[$index]['question_id'];
 $s_ans=User_Model::shuffle_answers($question_id);
  foreach ($s_ans as $s_a){
      echo "<input type='radio' name='test_ans[$index][$s_a]' id='$question_id' />$s_a <br />";

      }

 echo "<hr/>";
      $index++;

  }
```

The above code shows all questions and their answers at once.
What I would like to do, and couldn't successfully get it done, is to show each question separately and when the user presses the "next" button, the next question accompanied by its answers will be shown to him.

So,

a)is there a way I can achieve that?

b)when I try to access user's answers I get the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [I  like ice cream => on ) [1] => Array ( [i don't go to school] => on ) [2] => Array ( [i play basketball] => on ) [3] => Array ( [i like sailing] => on ) )
```

How can i access the user's answers as to compare them with the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipage quizzes are very easy to do.

A) This can be done by removing the `while()` loop, but leave the counter to pass through a hidden `<input>` OR increasing the `$_SESSION` variable

```
$index = $_POST['index'] // OR $_GET['index'] OR $_SESSION['index'] depending on your form method
echo $test[$index]['question']. "<br/>";
$question_id=$test[$index]['question_id'];
$s_ans=User_Model::shuffle_answers($question_id);
foreach ($s_ans as $s_a){
  echo "<input type='radio' name='test_ans[$index][$s_a]' id='$question_id' />$s_a <br />";
}

if ($index < $total_questions){
$index++; // Increase var, and then use in hidden input
echo "<input type='hidden' name='index' value='$index' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit_answer' value='Next' />";}
else {
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit_answer' value='You Are Done' />";}
//OR
$_SESSION['index'] = $index++;
```

B) Without your code, this is just an example -

```
if ($user[$index]['their answer'] == $test[$index]['right answer'])
   { echo "You were correct";}
else
   { echo "Sorry, your answer was incorrect";}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and the index doesn't increment as it should. It's value is always 0... ( My button is submit type button with name submitted_ans.)
I did manage to fix that. But how will the $index counter know when to stop incrementing? Should I make contional check to see whether it has passed the count($test) ?

Comment: You would need to do a conditional check, against your total questions, and only increment if less than. This can also be used to change your button from `Next` to `Done`. Updated with a sample `if` statement

Comment: Thanks for the idea! won't i have to use some javascript for that?

Comment: You could use javascript, but you already have the count in our original posted code - `(count($test)-1)`. You could save that as a session varible `$_SESSION['num_of_questions'] = (count($test)-1);` and then in the `if` statement - `if ($index < $_SESSION['num_of_questions'])

Comment: I know. I was reffering to changing the "next" button to Done...
What will happen when $index>$SESSION['num_of_questions']? How can I post the answres?
However i noticed something rather strange... it is possible that one can select up to 3 choices!!! Although the answers are displayed with a radio buttoon next to them...How is that possible?

Comment: To make them only able to select 1 radio button, all the radio buttons in the group have to have the same `name`, but different `value` and `id`. Change your button code to - `echo "<input type='radio' name='test_ans[$index]' value='$s_a' id='$question_id_$s_a' />$s_a <br />";`.

Comment: I would llike to pose a quick question: I want to store all the right answers to a session variable and then compare each one with the one that user provided. I have the following code `for ($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['total_questions'];$i++)
{
 
 $_SESSION['all_right_answers']=$test[$i]['right_answer'];
 
 }`
when I use `for($i=0;$i<count($test_ans);$i++){
 echo $_SESSION['all_right_answers'];
  }
 }`
all i get is the last right answer stored in the session variable.. Why is that?

Comment: Each time you go through the loop `($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['total_questions'];$i++)`, you are reseting `$_SESSION['all_right_answers']`. You will want to make `$_SESSION['all_right_answers']` an array, and then just add to that array in your loop. `$_SESSION['all_right_answers'] = array(); for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['total_questions'];$i++) { $_SESSION['all_right_answers'][$i]=$test[$i]['right_answer']; } for($i=0;$i<count($test_ans);$i++){ echo $_SESSION['all_right_answers'][$i]; }`

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're using PHP you can use sessions or cookies. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but I'd generate a reference string that represents a sequence of questions and store it in one session or cookie variable, and then have another session or cookie variable that represents the current position in the quiz. Furthermore you could have additional variables to keep track of score and other tidbits. Then when they hit the next button you just update variables and display the next question, or the end of the quiz if you've reached it.

If you want to do it dynamically without having to load another page then you'll need to look into javascript.